# How to refer to single digits within a number in ada?

Tags: numbers, ada

If I have a number like 1234, how do I refer specifically to the second digit of that number? The number is stored as a variable and var, width=>2 gives me 12. I need a way to isolate the 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by var, width => 2.  This is not Ada.

If the variable is a subtype  of `Integer`, then you can say:

```
declare 
   Var_As_String := Integer'Image(Var);
   Second_Digit : Character := Var_As_String(3);
begin
   -- Use second digit here.
end;
```

Note that the index is `3` because in the result of `Image`, the first character is either a minus sign or space.

Comment: Thank you! Quick clarification question, if my var is 1234 and I set Digit : Character := Var_As_String(6), will Digit = 0? or will it return an error? I'm trying to allow for var to be longer than four digits

Comment: An exception will be raised.   You can avoid this with `if 6 <= Var_As_String'Last then` get the 6'th digit.  Or you can catch and handle the exception.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, also consider the variation of [`Put`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html) that writes to a `String`.

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;
...
declare
   Var : constant Integer := 1234;
   Result : String(1 .. 4);
begin
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Result, Var);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Result(2));
end;
```